# cut a program in three files QML (Model / View / Controller)

Tags: model-view-controller, listview, qml

I want to separate my program into 3 QML files: One QML file that contains the data model (`XMLlistModel`), another that includes the views (`ListView`), and the third to launch the program.

```js
import QtQuick 1.0

Item {

    width: 800
    height: 480

    XmlListModel {
        id: forecastModel
        source: "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=&hl=fr"
        query: "/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_information"
        XmlRole { name: "city"; query: "city/@data/string()" }
    }

    ListView {
        x: 145; y: 325; width: 594; height: 48;
        model: forecastModel
        delegate: Text {
            font.family: "Univers LT Std"; color: "#c8c8c8"; width: parent.width; font.pixelSize: 30
            text: city
            anchors.centerIn: parent.centerIn
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like

ForecastModel.qml

```
XmlListModel {
    source: "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=&hl=fr"
    query: "/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_information"
    XmlRole { name: "city"; query: "city/@data/string()" }
}
```

ForecastView.qml

```
ListView {
    x: 145; y: 325; width: 594; height: 48;
    delegate: Text {
        font.family: "Univers LT Std"; color: "#c8c8c8"; width: parent.width; font.pixelSize: 30
        text: city
        anchors.centerIn: parent.centerIn
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Item {    
    width: 800
    height: 480

    ForecastModel {
        id: forecastModel
    }

    ForecastView {
        model: forecastModel
    }
}
```